# Copying 80 minute music CD to 700MB CD-R

Tags: itunes

I have copied 80 minutes of music (158MB) from an original CD into my iTunes library but my iTunes tell me it can't all be burned back to a new blank 700MB CD-R disk.

Q1.  Why can't I burn the full original 80mins?
Q2.  Is there a solution?
Q3.  If it is possible, will the reproduced CD be capable of playback on standard CD equipment?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 80 minutes is the limit for a regular CD-R. With pre-track gaps and whatnot, your audio may simple be a few seconds too long.

Comment: 80 minutes of music as AIF is not 158MB, of course, it's 700MiB, so you ripped it to something smaller, mp3, aac etc - this means you have to re-expand it to something approximating full size, which will not be a bit-match for the source. You should have imaged it if you wanted to duplicate it… then it would fit.

Comment: @Tetsujin nope, its not. 80 minutes of music in uncompressed WAV, cd-audio quality is 807MiB. Your conclusion is correct, just that small bit isn't.

Comment: @LPChip -  Yeah, sorry - I actually looked it up afterwards. It appears they squeezed the orange book standard [& therefore red book] by using finer data tolerances. Long time since I made a CD…  prolly made my first in 1992 [I had one of the very first Yamaha real-time recorders, then a 'full 1x data write speed' after that;)) & my last in maybe 2006...

Comment: @Tetsujin don't feel sorry, just needed to rectify the comment in case someone reads it and thinks: oh, so its the same... :) I'm actually an IT geek and mucisian, so I do know my fair share of audio stuff. You can look me up on spotify if you're interested. :)

Comment: @LPChip - Cool. Similarly, though I didn't think I was actually on Spotify, turns out I am ;)) Stretching as far back as 1981 [though seems to be only from a compilation released last year] The only thing I ever played on that was a hit, in 82, then an album from 85 & my last one from 2006 [I pretty much retired after that].

Comment: @Tetsujin cool! Will give it a listen. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129059/discussion-between-tetsujin-and-lpchip).

Answer (score 2):

80 Minutes of music is not the same as 700MB of WAV data.

In fact, an 80 minute audio CD does not hold the same amount of data as a 700MB Data cd, even if you think it would. When you want to store the music from iTunes to a cd, it will store it in RAW WAV data which doesn't fit.

Using a [WAV duration to size converter](https://www.colincrawley.com/audio-file-size-calculator/), we can figure out that 80 minutes of music is the same as 846.72 MB (megabytes) or 807.4951171875 MB (megabytes) / MiB.

This is quite a bit more than the 700 the cd offers.

That said, a data cd was not meant as a means to store audio. If you want a music cd, use an audio cd that has a number of minutes (These cd's are called CD-R Audio and list minutes instead of MBs. If you just want to store the songs and play it on your pc, then convert it to MP3's first, then you can fit a lot of songs on the cd, even if you go for a 650MB data cd.

Comment: There is no distinction between audio and data with CD-Rs. It’s up to the burning tool to create either an audio CD or a data CD. So I’m not sure this answer actually helpful/correct.

Comment: @DanielB yes there actually is. You can buy special audio CD-R's designed for audio, because if you don't the audio may not fit. Something like this: https://www.amazon.com/MAXELL-CDR-XLII-Audio-Spindle/dp/B000CCAQ0K/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=audio+cd+cd-r&qid=1630177058&sr=8-3

Comment: I’m sorry but that’s snake oil. Those are plain old 700 MB/80 min CD-R. It’s even on the packaging. Additionally, CD audio is stored very differently from Mode 1 CD data. No error correcting information means it’ll store 2,352 bytes of audio per sector whereas Mode 1 stores only 2048 bytes of data. You’ll see it will fit exactly.